# While Updating i'm getting this error, how can i resolve this?

Tags: linux

An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error:

```
https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve the key issue, in the last replace the key with your actual key.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B53DC80D13EDEF05
```

Comment: This worked for me, although I did get a warning when running the command: `Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead`